# JavaScript AutoComplete with php mysql

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have a javascript, it getting json data from data/city.php,, and is working good

```
var $kUI_autocomplete_template = $('#GJB_city');
        if($kUI_autocomplete_template.length) {
            $kUI_autocomplete_template.kendoAutoComplete({
                minLength: 2,
                dataTextField: "city",
                template:
                '<div class="k-list-wrapper">'+                  
                        '<span class="uk-text-muted uk-text-small">#: data.city #</span>' +
                    '</span>' +
                '</div>',
                dataSource: {
                    transport: {
                        read: {
                            dataType: "json",
                            url: "data/city.php"
                        }
                    }
                },
                height: 204
            }).data("kendoAutoComplete");
        }
```

now i am trying to get data by posting value to `data/city.php?like=value`
I need keyup function to get data from city.php as on city.php mysql is using like statement to find data.

I am noob with js so can any one help me with how can i post data and get it working i was trying doing

> url: "data/city.php?like=#: data.city #"

its wrong i know can any one please help.
I am using http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/autocomplete/template

Comment: so you basically want to get data from city.php on each keystroke?

Comment: @boroboris Yaa .. on city.php i am catching it with $like = $_GET['like']; and then it to mysql query.... what i need js to send data to city.php and read the result (its reading result but i am not able to send data)

Answer (score 0):

```
dataSource: {
    transport: {
       read: {
         dataType: "json",
          url: "data/city.php"
         }
       }
     },
                height: 204
}).data("kendoAutoComplete").then(function(value) {
   // do someting with data
  }, function(reason) {
  // console.log(reason);
});
```

[source on developer.mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then)

Comment: its already there... what i need a function to get data by using keyup function and post or get method to send data to data/city.php?like=value and get result from page